# Mocked method is returning null instead of expected object

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermockito

I have source code like below.

```
public class XYZClass {

    private static InitialContext ctx;

    private static InitialContext getCtx(){
        try{
            if(ctx == null)
                    ctx = new InitialContext();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return ctx;
    }
    public static IMFTPManagerService getIMFTPManagerFacade() {
        try {
            return (IMFTPManagerService) getCtx().lookup("abc");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to write test case for `getIMFTPManagerFacade()` method. I need to mock `getCtx()` method which is private and static and also `lookup("abc")` method. So I did it in the below way. I am not getting any error or any exception in mocking. Also when I debug the line individual method return values, the `getCtx()` method is returning the mocked object and `lookup()` method is also returning the required mocked object. But after completing the execution of that entire line `return (IMFTPManagerService) getCtx().lookup("abc");`, the line returns null to the test class method. Can any one find me a solution? If my question is not clear, please ask.

And here is the test class:

```
 @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
 @PrepareForTest(XYZClass.class)
 public class XYZClassTest {
    private InitialContext ctx;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(XYZClass.class);
        ctx = Mockito.spy(new InitialContext());
        PowerMockito.doReturn(ctx).when(XYZClass.class, "getCtx");

        IMFTPManagerBean service1 = new IMFTPManagerBean();
        Mockito.doReturn(service1).when(ctx).lookup(Mockito.eq("abc"));
    }


    @Test
    public void testGetIMFTPManagerFacade() {
        IMFTPManagerService service = XYZClass.getIMFTPManagerFacade();
        assertEquals(IMFTPManagerService.class, service.getClass());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you partially mock static methods of a class, you need to explicitely state if real implementation should be called (check `thenCallRealMethod` below).

If you don't that, any method you call would be treated as a method on a mock without specified behaviour, and thus return null.

On top of that:

- you use `EJBFacades` which was not posted in the question. I've rewritten the test in terms of `XYZClass`
- your assertion will fail, as you return a subclass of the service.

```
package com.test.powermock.teststacitejb;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

import javax.naming.InitialContext;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(XYZClass.class)
public class XYZClassTest {


    private InitialContext ctx;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(XYZClass.class);
        ctx = Mockito.spy(new InitialContext());
        PowerMockito.doReturn(ctx).when(XYZClass.class, "getCtx");

        IMFTPManagerBean service1 = new IMFTPManagerBean();
        Mockito.doReturn(service1).when(ctx).lookup(Mockito.eq("abc"));
        PowerMockito.when(XYZClass.getIMFTPManagerFacade()).thenCallRealMethod();
    }


    @Test
    public void testGetIMFTPManagerFacade() {
        IMFTPManagerService service = XYZClass.getIMFTPManagerFacade();
        assertTrue(service instanceof IMFTPManagerService);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late responce.... Sorry, it is not EJBFacades and it is XYZClass only. Changed the question... So even after using your solution, it is returning null object only.

Comment: I have 2 pieces of advice: 1. Add error logging in the catch statement of getIMFTPManagerFacade(). You need to find out if null is returned from InitialContext spy, or due to swallowed exception. 2. Check jUnit version (and annotation you use). Powermock runs only with jUnit4 (on jUnit 5 it needs a special jUnit4 vintage runner, which I use in my setup)

Comment: I am using JUnit4 only. PowerMockito worked fine for some other different tast cases But here it is not. Also I done with debugging it, mocked objects are not null. Also when I check both methods individuallyunder debug mode they are returning those mocked objects only... But when it completes executing that entire line, it is returning null object to our test methods... See my question... I already mentioned it there...

Comment: I made a minimal example that works for me:
https://github.com/lesiak/powermocktestjunit4